# What does "se jouer" mean here?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire

I have seen this sentence on Quora today, but I have failed to match the meaning of this word to the definitions listed in Larousse or translate it reliably:

*La différence entre l'infinitif et le participe passé **se joue** jusqu'à la phonétique ce qui ne se fait pas au premier groupe.*

Edit: this is the source: [Quora](https://fr.quora.com/Pourquoi-de-moins-en-moins-de-Fran%C3%A7ais-savent-diff%C3%A9rencier-le-%C3%A9-du-participe-pass%C3%A9-et-le-er-de-linfinitif-On-apprend-pourtant-%C3%A7a-%C3%A0-l%C3%A9cole-primaire-Avez-vous-des-astuces/answer/Yann-Goasguen)

Comment: The sixth definition in the French-English [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/jouer/44959) seems to be the one that you need. I can’t work out a translation yet that sounds natural in English though.

Comment: @Maroon interesting, bilingual dictionary had more meanings than their definition's dictionary...

Comment: It means **occurs**, but a phrasal verb that works is: plays out. The difference between the infinitive and the past participle plays out even in phonetics, which is not the case for the first group.

Comment: I’m a native French speaker; this sentence is nearly meaningless. Is it an automatic translation?

Comment: Where on Quora? I can't find it there...

Comment: @Lambie I added the source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the sentence is simply incorrect.

> La différence entre l'infinitif et le participe passé se joue jusqu'à la phonétique ce qui ne se fait pas au premier groupe.

"ce" makes reference to "la différence phonétique". But it's not good syntax to my knowledge. They mean :

> - La différence entre l'infinitif et le participe passé se joue jusqu'à la phonétique. Il n'y a pas de différence pour le premier groupe.
> - Difference between past participle and the infinitive comes down to phonetics. There is no difference for the first group.

As it is already well explained in other answers, the past participle and the infinitive form of first group verbs sounds the same (the others dont). Which is very confusing for a surprising number of french people as well.

---

Concerning "se jouer". As in other languages, a game **is** played ("game" is used in a passive way):

> - Je joue à ce jeu. Ce jeu **se joue** en intérieur
> - I play this game. This game **is** played indoors.

By extension it can be used when two things are in opposition.
**"Se jouer à"** is a rather common french expression. It refers to the things that made a difference.

For instance, a boxing match where a commentator would say:

> - Ca va être dur pour les juges de choisir un vainqueur, **ça se joue à un coup de poing ou deux** !
> - It will be hard for the juges to decide on a winner, **it's down to a punch or two** !

The most usual form I can think of is "ça se joue à peu" which could be translated in some contexts to "it's a close one". It can be used for anything. For instance:

> - Tu préfère ce bleu ou celui là ?
> - Hmmm, dur à dire. Celui là, mais ça se joue à peu...

Which translates to:

> - Which is your favorite blue ?
> - Hmmm, hard to say. This one, but it's a close one...

So, by saying:

> La différence entre l'infinitif et le participe passé se joue jusqu'à la phonétique.

It means that **you cannot make the difference until phonetics**.

Comment: Got a little carried away and ended up with a long answer, hope this helps anyway...

Comment: La différence se joue jusqu'à la limite de la realité. Quelque chose ne peut pas "se jouer jusqu'à x"? Je me pose la question.

Comment: "Se jouer jusqu'à" ne me choque pas du tout. Examples: [in this article](http://www.avenuedesecoles.com/index.php/tous-les-articles-sur-leducation-582/2475-tout-se-joue-jusqu-a-25-ans) and [this one](https://www.humanite.fr/industrie-le-sort-immediat-dalstom-se-joue-jusqua-minuit-643838).

Comment: Ceci dit, la phrase de la question est incorrecte et porte beaucoup à confusion.

Comment: La personne qui a écrit la phrase sur Quora est ingénieur (français) et par conséquent un haut niveau de formation. En tout cas, si "se jouer jusqu'à" ne vous choque pas, pourquoi rejettez-vous la phrase par ailleurs? Je cherche à comprendre, c'est tout.

Comment: Le niveau de formation importe peu, je connais des ingénieurs français compétents qui parlent très mal français par ailleurs. Je trouve que la phrase est incorrecte à cause du "ce" qui n'a pas de sens dans ce cas. Mais le début de la phrase employant "se joue" est correct, bien que mal formulé.
Dire "la différence entre X et Y se joue" implique que X et Y "se battent" pour faire la différence, ca a du sens. Dire "la différence entre X et Y joue" rend "la différence" sujet de la phrase, qui perd son sens selon moi.

Comment: La phrase en question disait: **jusqu'à la phonétique**. Je ne vois pas le "ce" que vous évoquez...

Comment: La phrase est : "La différence entre l'infinitif et le participe passé se joue jusqu'à la phonétique **ce** qui ne se fait pas au premier groupe."

Comment: Ah bon, pardon. Je comprends. le "ce qui" introduit une proposition relative. D'accord. Je pensais qu'on pouvait faire une phrase déclarative suivie d'une proposition relative....

Comment: A ma connaissance, on peut tout à fait: **"J'ai mangé beaucoup de pain, ce qui m'a donné mal au ventre"**. L'auteur aurait pu, par exemple, dire : **"La différence entre l'infinitif et le participe passé se joue jusqu'à la phonétique ce qui trouble beaucoup de français."**

Answer (score 12):

I think it's a very poor way to express what is meant here.  The idea is that the difference between the infinitive and the past participle of verbs is marked in French, it's always the case in writing :

- paré/parer
- fini/finir
- cru/croire

However, in spoken French, for many verbs, those from the so-called first group ending in *-er* in the infinitive, the past participle and the infinitive sound exactly the same :

- paré = parer transcribed /pare/ in IPA notation

I would have said to express this idea :

> - La différence entre l'infinitif et le participe passé est marquée phonétiquement sauf pour les verbes du premier groupe.

*Se jouer* gives the impression that something is in play, at stake, is not settled yet, which is not the case here.  For example, you could have :

- La paix du monde se joue au Conseil de sécurité des Nations Unies.

The only way I'd use *jouer* in your sentence is without the *se* as a loose synonym for producing some kind of effect:

- La différence entre l'infinitif et le participe passé joue jusqu'à la phonétique ce qui ne se fait pas au premier groupe.

But the phrasing is not very good.

Comment: I entirely agree with you, this sentence is pompous with no effort to be clear. A paradox when one is trying to explain the language.

Comment: Your French sentence is very clear and grammatically correct, unlike the original ;)

Comment: se jouer se dirait ici: play out. Vous pensez en tant que francophones que: se jouer jusqu'à/au x ne peut pas s'écrire? Pour moi, ça fait  tournure typique "intello". Mais c'est vrai qu'il y a des styles moins compliqués pour ce contexte.

Comment: "Se jouer jusqu'à" se dit et s'entend, on peut le trouver dans des articles de presse donc je suppose que c'est aussi correct à l'écrit (la presse n'est malheureusement plus une référence). Par contre pour moi, cela ferait partie d'un language plutôt familier que soutenu.

Answer (score -2):

The relevant definition in the French-English [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/jouer/44959) is found Under "se jouer" and is the second one in that section;

> (soutenu) [produire un effet]

It corresponds to [TLFi **II A 1** emploi pronominal réfléchi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/jouer);

> Emploi pronom. réfl.
>
> - Un ruisseau qui se joue dans la prairie (Ac. 1835-1935).
> - Autour de ce bâton, dans des méandres capricieux, se jouent et folâtrent des tiges et des fleurs (BAUDEL., Poèmes prose, 1867, p. 313).
>
> Au fig. Se donner libre cours.
>
> - Je vous encourage fort à nous faire connaître les personnages de cette grotte : laissez votre imagination se jouer à son aise : elle est belle, tendre et féconde (CHATEAUBR., Corresp., t. 1, 1803, p. 125).

There seems to be a problem of ajustment, the possible omission of semantic variants in the dictionary definitions;
the difference between "avoir libre cours" and "se donner libre cours" is a thin one; for instance, in the last example, saying "laissez votre imagination avoir libre cours" and "donnez libre cours à votre imagination" mean the same thing; moreover, if we apply the definition verbatim in that example, we  have a less usual variant where the imagination takes on the part of the subject ("laissez votre imagination se donner libre cours") but the meaning remains very close.

In truth, the term which  seems most relevant is "se produire" or similarly "avoir libre cours" and not "produire un effet" or "se donner libre cours". There is, to compound the diffilculty in this sentence,  a  term not quite non logical: "ce qui ne se fait pas"; the meaning of "faire" does not correspond to the context: in the negative form "se faire" does not mean "se produire" ([TLFi, faire² **II A 2**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/faire)) and anyway the form is too different (il se fait que). The deduction that the negative form is not defined is mine and I find no confirmation for it in the linguistic literature.

- Il se fait que ces choses-là arrivent.
- <s>Il ne se fait pas que des gens restent sans manger aussi longtemps.</s>

It seems that there does not exist another sens of "se faire" that will fit this context; in particular "se faire" cannot be used as a proxy verb for "se produire".

The proper verb would have been a verb such as "être le cas" in a form such as "ce qui n'est pas le cas".

- La différence entre l'infinitif et le participe passé **a libre cours** jusqu'à la phonétique, ce qui n'est pas le cas au premier groupe. (*ce qui ne se passe pas, ce qui ne se produit pas*)
- La différence entre l'infinitif et le participe passé **se produit** jusqu'à la phonétique, ce qui n'est pas le cas au premier groupe.

This means that the difference between the two forms is **carried over** from the spelling to the pronunciation.

entendre/entendu ==> ɑ̃tɑ̃dʁə/ɑ̃tɑ̃dy (the difference carries over to the pronunciation, is still present in the pronunciation)

chanter/chanté ==> ʃɑ̃te/ʃɑ̃te (does not carry over to the pronunciation)

Comment: Le sens de se jouer (soutenu) produire un effet en anglais, ici, serait: play out;

Comment: @Lambie Bizarre, Deepl me donne « se dérouler » et un dictionnaire d'Oxford me donne en explication « when an event  is played out it happens »; the Merriam-Webster dictionary does not mention it either https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/play%20out (« unfold » de nouveau mais pas « produire un effet) ». « Produire un effet » serait un sens rare de ce verbe ?

Comment: @Lambie Il me semble que vous confondez avec « se jouer, emploi passif », verbe qui signifie bien « se dérouler ».

Comment: Yes, when something plays out,  it happens. happens=occurs. Mais on ne trouve pas cela mot-à-mot dans les dicos.

Comment: Pas du tout. se joue dans la phrase est to play out: the difference plays out even in the phonetics....Le défi se joue sur tous les fronts. The challenge plays out/is playing out on all fronts. occurs, happens, not unfolding (se dérouler)

Comment: @Lambie According to what I understand a difference cannot "happen", or "occur" and also, since it's the same, it cannot "play out"; semantically those concepts do not go together (whether in French or English). "la différence se déroule …" seems an unthinkable utterance.